# Point of intersection of circle and binary image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: Binary Image]

I have skeletonize binary image and the junction information. I want to draw circle at junction points as center and want to find the point of intersection of circle and binary image.
I have written the following code:

```
 BW = imread('circles.png');
 imshow(BW);
 BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'remove');
 figure, imshow(BW2)
 BW3 = bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf);
 figure, imshow(BW3)
 BW3t = bwmorph(BW3,'thin');
 figure, imshow(BW3t)


 [rj, cj, re, ce] = findendsjunctions(BW3t, 1);
 hold on 
 plot(cj(1),rj(1),'ob')
 hold on
 circle([cj(1),rj(1)],4,50,':r');
```

findendsjunctions.m and dependent file show.m can downloaded from here: http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/LineSegments/findendsjunctions.m and here http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Misc/show.m respectively. 
And circle.m can be downloaded from here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2876-draw-a-circle/content/circle.m

I want to find whether circle intersect 2, 3 or 4 vessels around it (marked as star in an image). Even if circle transverse many times a single vessel but output should be one intersection point per vessel.

Please suggest how can I find the intersection of circle and binary vessels.

Thanks

Comment: and your question ? what have you tried to do so far? you have links to other codes, what was the problem in implementing these codes?

Comment: @natan There is no problem in implementing above code above but my next step is to find point of intersection of circle and binary image. I want to find the 3 points (marked as star in an image) where circle meets the binary vessels. You can suggest how?

Comment: see Andrey's  webpage: https://matlabcorner.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the point of intersection of circle and Binary image and the coordinates of 3 points (marked as star in an image provided with my question). I have change the function circle.m (mentioned in my question above ) to give output of all X and Y coordinates of circumference of the circle and then I have written the following matlab code:

```
   [H, X, Y]=circle([cj(1),rj(1)],4,50,':r');
   c = improfile(BW3t,X,Y)
   x=1:length(c)
   figure
   plot(x, c,'r')
```

[image: Number of peaks represent where circle cuts the binary image]

```
   [maxtab, mintab]=peakdet(c, 1)
   [pks,locs] = findpeaks(c)
   pt1=[X(locs(1)) Y(locs(1))]
   pt2=[X(locs(2)) Y(locs(2))]
   pt3=[X(locs(3)) Y(locs(3))]

   hold on
   plot(pt1(1),pt1(2),'om','LineWidth',2)
   hold on
   plot(pt2(1),pt2(2),'og','LineWidth',2)
   hold on
   plot(pt3(1),pt3(2),'ob','LineWidth',2)
```

pt1, pt2 pt3 are three points where circle cuts the binary image